# Issue with $softDelete in model testing

Tags: unit-testing, model, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel-test-helper package by jeffrey way in laravel 4 to test my models. When I use

```
protected $softDelete = true;
```

in my model, the following assertion fails:

```
public function testMyModel()
{

    $obj = Factory::create('Modelname');
    Assert::equals(1,$obj->count());
}
```

and when I run the test without the $softDelete variable, it works fine.
Any clue to whats wrong?
This is the stack trace of the phpunit command, if it is of any help:

```
/var/www/project/vendor/way/laravel-test-helpers/src/Way/Tests/TestFacade.php:41
/var/www/project/vendor/way/laravel-test-helpers/src/Way/Tests/TestFacade.php:25
/var/www/project/vendor/way/laravel-test-helpers/src/Way/Tests/TestFacade.php:55
/var/www/project/app/tests/models/ModelTest.php:13
/var/www/project/app/tests/models/ModelTest.php:13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Factory::create()` will create random variables for your models. Because your are using 'softDelete' - there is a field in your table called '`deleted_at`'. So the factory is putting data in there, and Laravel thinks the record is deleted, so `->count()` returns 0.

You need to explicitly set Factory default for the deleted_at to `null` like this:

```
$obj = Factory::create('Modelname', array('deleted_at' => null));
```